# Handling httprequest execution timeout scenario

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, timeout, httprequest

My ASP.Net Web service have a httprequest execution timeout as 110 seconds (default value). I want a custom exception to be thrown to my client app if the processing time crosses 110 seconds. How and where to handle this?

Comment: Surely a better approach would be to make a system that doesn't get to the point of hitting the execution timeout, something asynchronous perhaps?

Comment: Yes I agree,but I have to live with the current architecture for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a workaround, not a good solution though.

I could get the exception info in Application_Error event in Global.ASAX by using 
Server.GetLastError();
I didn't succeed in sending custom exception. I will ask my client side dev to check for HTML content before trying to parse as SOAP xml.